# Ways to speed up termination of socket WinHttp APIs using C++ for Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, winsock, winhttp

I have a Windows service application written in C++/MFC that establishes an HTTP connection via Windows sockets. It employs [WinHttp* APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do all the socket related operations. It all works great, except when someone tries to stop/uninstall that service if it's in the process of connecting via the socket (espeically in a situation when such connection could not be established, like, say, if my Internet cable is unplugged) those socket APIs do not return for several seconds before the service can close (obviously, the mechanism inside the service waits for my socket thread to finish "gracefully".)

My question is, if I have an open socket handle, as well connection and request handles (of HINTERNET type), obtained from a call to WinHttpOpen(), WinHttpConnect() and WinHttpOpenRequest(), is there any way to forcefully make any other WinHttp* APIs that may be currently working with the socket to return immediately?

PS. I was thinking to do so from a main thread before it begins waiting for the socket thread to close (before uninstalling/stopping the service.)

Comment: as far as i know, WinHttpOpen uses hard-coded blocking connect() to establish the connection. You'd probably want to go with other(or your own) http library to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Hmm... That's bad, becuase it'd be a pain to write all the code... But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can close your WinHTTP handle from another thread. This breaks the blocking call on the main thread with the delay you are trying to avoid. See [How can a synchronous WinHttp request be cancelled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939316/how-can-a-synchronous-winhttp-request-be-cancelled)

Answer (score 0):

[obviously, the mechanism inside the service waits for my socket thread to finish "gracefully']  - if you know the cause of the problem, why not remove it?

Why are you waiting?